# Objective C Callback on particular event

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I am new to objective C and trying to develop my own callback function, the callback function gets called on a particular event like receiving data from network like `NSURLprotocol` does and once received it will **NSLog** a message that "*Event has Occured*" or display as text on `UIViewController` or any **UI** related action.

So, I am totally confused as to where the `eventOccuredMethod` should be called to let the `receiveController` be called and execute the implementation inside it.

I have used protocols like `NSURLProtocol` before, but I don't know how to implement them to get such callbacks being called.

Any video links, answers, articles links are welcomed.

```
//Sample.h file 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Sample;
@protocol SampleProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)receivedCallback;
@end

@interface Sample : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<SampleProtocol> delegate;
-(void)eventOccured;
@end
```

//Sample.m file

```
#import "Sample.h"

@implementation Sample
-(void)eventOccured{
    if([_delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SampleProtocol)])
    [_delegate receivedCallback];
}
@end
```

//ViewController.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SampleProtocol>

@end
```

//ViewController.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

    Sample *s;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    s = [[Sample alloc] init];
    s.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)receivedCallback:(Sample *)sample{
    NSLog(@"Event Has Occured");
}

@end
```

I am not sure of the following call which I am making ...

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    Sample *s = [[Sample alloc] init];
    [s eventOccured];
}
```

Comment: The sample code you have posted is exactly how you implement the delegate pattern. I don't understand what your question / issue is

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin : From where the eventOccured Method should be called. How does compiler know which method to invoke .. like how does compiler know that applicationHasReceivedData and call the applicationDidReceiveData method in NSURLProtocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing the delegate pattern the right way. But if the `Sample` object doesn't generate its own events but instead is relaying events posted to it from somewhere else, as is the case in your example, you have to ensure that the object which has the `ViewController` as a delegate and the object that receives the message are in fact the same. One way to do it is to make `Sample` a singleton :

```
#import "Sample.h"

@implementation Sample

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static id sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)eventOccured{
    if([_delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SampleProtocol)])
        [_delegate receivedCallback];
}

@end
```

And then in your view controller you would do

```
s = [Sample sharedInstance];
```

and in your appDelegate :

```
[[Sample sharedInstance] eventOccured];
```

Another way to ensure that you are using the same object, as vikingosegundo pointed out, would be to set the view controller's Sample object from the appDelegate.

For this use case, you could also consider using Notifications.

Comment: Yes, I liked this simple implementation. Yes I considered this notifications, but my application is going to do lot many things, and lot more call backs, so i had discard using notifications.

Comment: using singleton like this is considered an "anti-pattern" among experienced developer, as it hides dependencies and states and therefor makes unit testing hard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Answer (score 1):

?, i'm very confused. I don't think you understand what you have written. You should never try copy code like this from online without first reading a tutorial to understand what it is you are doing. This can be very dangerous.

`Sample.h / .m` is a class, this class defines a protocol that says "In order for me to alert you to the fact an event has occurred, you need to implement method X".

This is the "protocol", by conforming to the protocol, another class (lets say a ViewController) is saying that it implements the method that `Sample` is looking for.

So `Sample` will run code, and when it wants to pass some info back to the other class (ViewController in this case) it calls one of the methods defined in the protocol.

e.g. (not fully working code)

Sample.m

```
- (void)getDataFromURL:(NSStirng *)url
{
     [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
            if([_delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SampleProtocol)])
            {
                 [_delegate receivedCallback];
            }
     }];
}
```

So when `Sample` runs the method `getDataFromURL` it will request its data, when the data returns, `Sample` will call the method `receivedCallback` on its delegate. Which in this case is an instance of a `viewController`.

**EDIT**

please also note what `[_delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SampleProtocol)]` does. This asks does the delegate instance conform to the protocol. But this protocol hasn't said that `recievedCallback` is required. So you have no way of knowing the method is there.

either use:

```
@protocol SampleProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void)receivedCallback;

@end
```

in the protocol definition or

```
if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(receivedCallback)])
```

to check is it implemented

Comment: From where should this getDataFromURL be called ?

Comment: @NileshAgrawal .... from where ever it needs to be. The protocol in this case is used to alert the delegate instance that the method `getDataFromURL` is done. So you call `getDataFromURL` from where ever you need to call `getDataFromURL`. Inside a `viewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, inside another method of another class etc. That is up to you to decide where it needs to be called

Comment: Thanks for your answer .Specially I liked the edit part of answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `eventOccured` on a second, independent Sample instance that has now delegate set.

The easiest fix: make the view controller send it to it's sample instance.

better: give  the view controller a property that holds sample and sat that from the application delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `EventOccurred` within your data retrieving method. Once the data retrieving is complete call EventOccured.

```
@protocol SampleProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)receivedCallback;
@end
```

This protocol must be implemented in your data retrieving class. And make sure `-(void)receivedCallback;` has a parameter to send data to your ViewController